# android 2.2 data still exists after uninstall

Tags: android, webview, uninstallation

I have an app using purely webview. I also stored some ids using SharedPreferences.

I realised that even after clearing data, and uninstall, some data still appears to exist. because when I reinstall the app, the webviews which points to a login url, still shows the login id. only when I reset the device to factory default, then the login credentials will disappear.

is there something wrong here?

Comment: It should be cleared when you uninstall the application.See when retrieving the preference the default value you have given.There is a possibility of messing with the default value

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy of your activity wrtie this

```
            yourWebView.clearCache(true);
            yourContext.deleteDatabase("webview.db");
            yourContext.deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");
```

Comment: hi, actually what i mean is that, when i go into 'manage applications', where i can 'clear cache', 'clear data', 'uninstall', even after i 'clear data' and 'uninstall' the app, some data still appears to exist on the device..

Comment: ya i am getting you, but above will help you in clearing the data(credentials) from webview, i need more eleboration for your problem

Comment: because i thought when i clear data and uninstall the app, everything related to the app should be deleted. hence the next time when i install the app again, which is suppose to be a clean install since i already uninstalled, there shouldnt have any cache/data/whatever exists. but apparently there are, because the app which is a webview, still has the login credentials.

Comment: but i think when you uninstall the app, then the whole package folder gets delete so how  can it have the value?

Comment: that's why i am puzzled. only when i reset the device to factory default, then the login credentials are gone..

Answer (score 0):

You are saving data into sharedpreferences which is stored in an xml file in /data/data/(package name)/shared_prefs directory. This data cannot be clear by clearing cache. To remove it, you have to be in your application and get SharedPreferences.Editor and call `editor.clear()` and then `editor.commit()`.